# Windows 7 goto Standby Mode

Tags: vb.net

I need to standby the remote computer(windows 7) in given time. Can any help me on this scenario. Is it is possible. to do by VB.Net.

there are Server and clients...
From server machine I need to standby(windows 7) the 
client system given time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PsShutdown utility from the SysInternals Toolkit

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx

You can just call the utility from your server using command-line in your VB app.